# Checking identity by multiplying matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I have nine $4 \times 4$ matrices, denoted by $S = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_9\}$.

I want to see, for some constant $k$ whose value is known, whether there exists a choice of $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k$, not necessarily distinct, such that the sequence
$$M = B_1 B_2 \cdots B_k$$
is the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix, where each $B_i \in S$.

What might be a code for it and can the same procedure also find that choice of $B_i$-s?

Comment: What are the elements of the ${A_i}s$? Integer/Real/Complex? Do ${B_i}s$ have to be distinct?

Comment: since the numbers are small, why not just try until you find such a set? using n choose k, where n=9 and k is the constant. This gives you all the combinations of matrices to try? Multiply each combination until you get identity matrix or use all combinations. For example 9 choose 5 gives 126 different sets to try. This should not take much time to compute in Mathematica.

Comment: Since order matters in matrix multiplication you need all possible permutations, not combinations actually. ofcourse this is the brute force method. But your set is small, so this does not matter.

Comment: The elements of $A_i$s are complex numbers. The $B_i$s do not need to be distinct. The numbers can be quite large. For example, if $k$ is 10, it is $9^{10}$ matrices to brute-force search from, which is not practical.

Comment: I do not see how you will find out which permutation will give identity matrix when all multiplied without trying. In this case, I think this is a math question not a Mathematica programming question. You might want to ask about it in the math group, and for implementation you could ask here if needed. just a suggestion. btw, you show that `n=9` so `k` can not be larger than 9? Because that is the size of the set to select from.

Comment: Yes, but there could be repetitions from the set S, so k could be as large as possible. Also, why isn’t it a Mathematica question? The part I am stuck on is an implementation of the code that repeatedly checks for whether the multiplication gives an identity matrix, and outputs the sequence when it does.

Comment: Could you edit the question to improve the equations. It's not really clear what you mean - in the second equation you're saying S is a matrix product of the Bs, but in the first one it's a set.

Comment: Maybe you could try turning this into a group theory problem then using `GroupElementToWord` [like I did in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231385/72682) which represents a group element in terms of its generators. Whether it works in practice really depends on the size of the closure of the matrix sequence though.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @BlackHat18 if the $A_i$ generators form a semigroup, then this might be related to the Identity Problem / group membership problem and you could exploit the structure. Those are hard - in some cases, undecidable problems however.

Comment: Please provide 9 such matrices and a value for $k$, so that people can try. This is standard on this forum. You should also clarify what the scope of your question is. In the comments you say that brute force may be impractical, yet at the same time you claim that only the implementation is missing. Which is it? Do you have an algorithm and are asking how to implement it? If so, what is the algorithm? Or you are asking people to come up with a better-than-brute-force algorithm for you?